# Network-Wide Plugin Settings Management

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, multisite, options

I'm using WordPress 3.1.2, and have three blogs in a WordPress network. I would like to change some settings for a specific plugin, but have the changes applied to all the blogs on the network. I can't change plugin settings on the "Network Admin", and instead have to do it on the "Site Admin" page for each individual blog.

I'm looking for the ability to change settings "sitewide" as is done, for example, by [this outdated plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-wpmu-sitewide-options/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the plugin developer and how they incorporate settings. The other option is to try and put it inside the /wp-content/mu-plugins but I'm not sure if that will allow you to have only a master setting. You could also try hard coding it in the plugin files. What plugin is it? I might be able to better help you.

Comment: At this time, it's the [Janrain Engage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/) plugin, but I was asking in general since I have three blogs with the same exact set of plugins and am forced to change settings on each individually.

Comment: unfornately i do not think it is quite easy to establish the best i could tell you is to just look at the files and see where it calls and possibly try to divert that into just one main or like i said before edit the plugin files with the defaults you want and store it inside mu-plugins. But i would only do this if you are going to have more then just the three sites

Comment: no problem. One last thing maybe ask the dev if they are working of have a solution already. Some do and some dont.