# How do I share plugin settings across WordPress network?

Tags: multisite, options

I am using multisite to translate WordPress website and I have the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/nmedia-user-file-uploader/
which I want to be accessible from all languages. From all site you should see the same uploaded content and settings.
How can I achieve that?
Currently if I upload in one language I won't be able to see in another.

Comment: Support for specific plugin or theme is off-topic here.

Comment: @Nilambar - Since the question of how to get settings to propagate across blogs is plugin-agnostic, I think it is on-topic.  Besides, where else could Rob ask such a question?

Answer (score 4):

The generic way to do it, is by using the `pre_option_{option}` https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_(option_name) filter to override the "local" settings and use the value being stored in your "main" sub site.

something like

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_the_plugin_option_name', function () {
  // Code assumes that "blog" 1 is the main one in which the relevant settings are stored.
  if (get_current_blog_id() != 1) {
    return get_blog_option(1, 'the_plugin_option_name');
  }

  return false;
}
```

Depending on the complexity of the plugin, it might not be enough and you will need additional overrides, but this type of code should be enough for simple cases.

Answer (score -1):

I almost thought this was a duplicate to [Network-Wide Plugin Settings Management](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15939/network-wide-plugin-settings-management) , but I see you also want shared content.

Basically, this is tough and situation and plugin dependent.  I'm a fan of WPMUDev's premium New Blog Template for copying content and settings upon blog creation, but it doesn't help with subsequent settings and content changes.

WPMUDev also has [MultiSite Content Copier](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multisite-content-copier/) which might work for you.  I haven't tried it myself, but it looks reasonable.  There may very well be other, and cheaper, options, too.

I hope this helps - good luck.

Comment: copying content means that you always have to keep in mind that you need to copy it on every change, and that you are not allowed to change it by mistake on other sites. This might be good enough when you intent to "fork" the content and settings, but not when you need them in sync